# How do I separate all the strings in a column and paste each substring into other columns? (by VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I have strings like this in column A:

```
aa-bb-cc-123

aa-bb-cc-345

aa-bb-cc-789

etc...
```

How do I separate the string by "-" in VBA and have each sub-string pasted in different columns? As an example:

```
column W    column X    column Y    column Z

aa          bb          cc          123

aa          bb          cc          456

aa          bb          cc          789
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to use VBA for such a simple task? If no then use TEXT TO COLUMNS ;) EDIT: I see @Tarik has laready suggested that :)

Comment: I agree that text to columns would be the way to go in most cases, but it doesn't Fill the correct columns (W to V) and would overwrite B to D and destroy the contents of column A.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following code:

```
Sub split_AtoW()

Dim x As Long, mydata
For x = 1 To Range("A65526").End(xlUp).Row 'x = first row here, so change to 2 if header row exists
    mydata = split(Range("A" & x), "-") 'put data in column A into an array split by "-"
    Range("W" & x).Resize(1, UBound(mydata) + 1).Value = mydata 'put data in the split array into W onwards
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Start recording a macro. When ready, through the data menu, select text to columns. Follow the wizard to the end. Stop recording. Check out the macro code and modify it as needed.

Comment: + 1 on suggesting Text To Columns. I still feel that for such a simple task, VBa is not required. :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, "-")
        For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            r.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = ary(i)
        Next i
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This would need a little mod to fill W to  Z as requested in the question and could go off on one if multiple columns were selected.